# linux-kernel: how can I use async io in kernel space

Tags: file, asynchronous, linux-kernel

Currently I'm using `vfs_write` and `vfs_read` to do the sync file io.
Is it possible to use `async io` in kernel space? Examples will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this information is reasonably up to date, but check the [Performing Direct I/O](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-3) chapter from Linux Device Drivers.